# python with tor and reddit "KeyError"

Tags: python, reddit, tor, keyerror

I found this code on github: https://github.com/Abrand88/Reddit-Tor-proxy-voting-bot/blob/master/reddit_proxy_voting_bot.py

I know that its a bot and potentially malicious but I thinks its cool nonetheless. From an educational perspective how do I get it working?: When I run the program it outputs "socket:" twice and then gives the error "KeyError: '127.0.0.1'"

Any thoughts?

Comment: so you grab some random code that you think is malicious, run it, and then wonder why it's not working? Do you dive off a cliff to check if there's rocks below it?

Comment: I love how people try to justify use of illicit software by randomly throwing in the phrase "educational purposes" or "educational perspective", thinking that somehow makes it okay.

Comment: Even ignoring all that, there isn't really enough information here to solve the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's using a dictionary and can't find the key for your local host.

this is probably causing the error breaking:

```
ip_hash={}; # the dictionary is made
```

and

```
ip_hash[ip] = 1; # the dictionary is incorrectly accessed
```

this part alone isn't a good idea:

```
if ip in ip_hash:
    print " repeat " + ip;
else:
    ip_hash[ip] = 1;
```

Comment: do you know how i fix this?

Comment: I would just redo the code personally; you really don't want to do this though; if reddit finds out they might start throwing ip bans everywhere :/